# Prevent ag-grid filter from duplicating options in conditions

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a column definition to which I apply a filter:

```
{
      headerName: t("value"),
      field: "value",
      filter: "agNumberColumnFilter",
      filterParams: {
        filterOptions: ["greaterThanOrEqual", "lessThanOrEqual"],
      },
```

When I start filtering, I am presented with the "greater than or equal" option to which I can assign a value, creating Condition 1.

That brings up Condition 2, and the default option is "greater than or equal" - the user then has to manually change that to "less than or equal To":

[image: ag-grid screen grab]

Having two "greater than or equal" conditions will never make sense... Ideally, for Condition 2 I would like to suppress whatever option was selected for Condition 1. Failing that, is there a way to at least change the default option for Condition 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most use cases do not demand a composite filter for filtering grid values.

If you do not wish to see two value comparison Filters, you can simply add the below optoins to your filterParams, so that the second filter never shows up.

```
headerName: t("value"),
field: "value",
filter: "agNumberColumnFilter", 
filterParams: 
{
      filterOptions: ['greaterThanOrEqual', 'lessThanOrEqual'],
      defaultOption: 'greaterThanOrEqual',
      suppressAndOrCondition: true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `filterParams.defaultOption` = `'empty'` which will make both condition 1 and 2 have nothing selected by default. Probably not the ideal solution you're looking for, but unfortunately there is not any way to configure condition 1 or 2 to have different options.